# how to select row when column must satisfy multiple value?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I've got a table

```
name | ability

kevin|say
kevin|scream
nike |say
```

I wanna get only kevin in response, when looking for `say` and `scream`. Count of parameters may change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT name
FROM t
WHERE ability in ('say', 'scream')
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE name='kevin' AND ability IN ('say','scream');
```

Another way to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE name='kevin' AND (ability='say' || ability='scream');
```

Good luck!!

Comment: Of course I haven't name value before query executing.

Comment: Maybe this then: `SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE ability IN ('say','scream');` Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT name FROM tablename WHERE ability IN ('say', 'scream') GROUP BY name
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tablename WHERE ability IN ('say', 'scream')
```

EDIT: Oh, you're looking for names that have *both* abilities... Then you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name from tablename WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM tablename WHERE ability = 'say') AND name IN (SELECT name FROM tablename WHERE ability = 'scream')
```

Or better yet, you can add a `HAVING` clause to the first query:

```
SELECT name FROM tablename WHERE ability IN ('say', 'scream') GROUP BY name HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Both of advices return `kevin` and `nike`. It's right, `IN` condition suggest logic "OR", so one of ability is satisfy.

Comment: inserted select is too hard and long with increase of conditions. The solution of topic work fine, thanks.